# expected '(' before 'val' Arduino error code

Tags: c++, arduino

Okay so I'm new to Arduino coding. I am trying to create a program that will turn on a series of LEDs based on the analog input of a potentiometer. This is the code I wrote:

```
#define red 4
#define blue 3
#define yellow 2



void setup() {

  pinMode(red, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(blue, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(yellow, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  int val = digitalRead(A0);
  if val <= 341(digitalWrite(red, HIGH)

  if val >= 682(digitalWrite(red, HIGH); digitalWrite(blue, HIGH);

  if val >= 1023(digitalWrite(red, HIGH); digitalWrite(blue, HIGH); digitalWrite(yellow, HIGH);)
}
```

I keep getting the error code "expected '(' before 'val'", Does anyone know what that means and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have incorrect C syntax in if's. Here is how to do it:

```
  if(val <= 341){
     digitalWrite(red, HIGH);
  }

  if(val >= 682 && val < 1023){
      digitalWrite(red, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(blue, HIGH);
  }

  if(val >= 1023){
      digitalWrite(red, HIGH); 
      digitalWrite(blue, HIGH); 
      digitalWrite(yellow, HIGH);
  }
```